# Getting an Value Error from using the mean squared error loss function

Tags: neural-network, regression

I am training a feed-forward neural network that takes in the input of shape `(4040 ,2)` and output of shape `(4040, 4, 51)`.

I tried using the Panda data frame for it first, however, it does not seem to work with a 3-dimensional output shape. (If there is a way to covert 3-dimensional data into Panda data frame please let me know)

So for now I am using numpy array to store the inputs and outputs. But they are now the same shape, and will raise and error when going through the mean squared error loss function.

Any comments, solutions and suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: seems like a so error, it is not entirely clear what you are trying to achieve, but the syntax seems to be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```py
def build_model90():
    input_layer = Input(shape = (2,))

    dense_1 = Dense(units='1024', activation='relu')(input_layer)
    dense_2 = Dense(units='512', activation='relu')(dense_1)
    
    # NOTE: yields 4 outputs directly each with size 51 
    y_output = Dense(units=4 * 51, name='output')(dense_2)
    y_output = Reshape((4, 51))(y_output)

    # Define the model with the input layer and a list of output layers
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=y_output)
    return model

forward_90 = build_model90()

optimizer = "Adam"

# NOTE: custom MSE loss
def mse_loss(x, y):
    # x and y have shape (B, 4, 51)
    error = tf.square(x - y)

    # sum over 4 and 51 dimensions
    loss = tf.reduce_sum(error, axis=[1, 2])

    # average over batch size
    return tf.reduce_mean(loss)

forward_90.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=mse_loss)

# NOTE: data reshaping
def reshape_data(x, y):
    return tf.reshape(x, shape=(-1, 2)), \
           tf.reshape(y, shape=(-1, 4, 51))

# prepare training and validation data
x_train, y_train = reshape_data(repeated_norm_train_dime, train_resp)
x_valid, y_valid = reshape_data(norm_test_dime, test_resp)

# Train the model for 100 epochs
epochs = 100
history_90 = forward_90.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=epochs, batch_size=4040,
                            validation_data=(x_valid, y_valid))
```

Explaination:

- I redefined the model architecture to output one tensor (and not four) with shape `(4,51)`. After training you can recover individual tensors by indexing, like `y_i = output[:, i]`.
- Then I defined a custom MSE loss, that sums over the dimensions `4` and `51` averaging over the batch size.
- Then, to be sure of the shape of the data I reshape them to `(N, 2)` and `(N,4,51)`.

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Yes, it works wonderfully! Thank you so much!
This is amazing, I'm so grateful for your help!